# Push value in multi dimensional object array - Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a dynamic multi dimensional object array and i want to push the new values inside the inner array as in example below.

```
columnType: any[][] = [
        [
            { Id: '1', Name: 'First Name' },
            { Id: '2', Name: 'Last Name' },
            { Id: '3', Name: 'Email' }
        ],
        [
            { Id: '1', Name: 'First Name' },
            { Id: '2', Name: 'Last Name' },
            { Id: '3', Name: 'Email' }
        ],
        [
            { Id: '1', Name: 'First Name' },
            { Id: '2', Name: 'Last Name' },
            { Id: '3', Name: 'Email' }
        ]
     ]
```

I need to push elements in inner array as per requirement as in below example

```
[
    [
        { Id: '1', Name: 'First Name' },
        { Id: '2', Name: 'Last Name' },
        { Id: '3', Name: 'Email' },
        { Id: '4', Name: 'Voice Phone' }
    ],
    [
        { Id: '1', Name: 'First Name' },
        { Id: '2', Name: 'Last Name' },
        { Id: '3', Name: 'Email' },
        { Id: '4', Name: 'Voice Phone' }
    ],
    [
        { Id: '1', Name: 'First Name' },
        { Id: '2', Name: 'Last Name' },
        { Id: '3', Name: 'Email' },
        { Id: '4', Name: 'Voice Phone' }
    ]
 ]
```

The code i tried

```
let val={ Id: '4', Name: 'Voice Phone' };
for(var i=0;i<this.columnType.length;i++){
      for(var j=0;j<this.columnType[i].length;j++){
        this.columnType[i][j].push(val);
      }
    }
```

Comment: You don't want to use `j` at all here; just `this.columnType[i].push(val)`;

Comment: @jcalz Tried with that it did not work. I got Error code: Out of Memory.

Comment: Also you'd better not to use `any`. Otherwise there is no reason for using TypeScript.

Comment: @jtouchlogic you should totally remove inner cycle and use single `push` instead. Otherwise you are pushing forever and getting `out of memory` error.

Comment: Yeah, you don't want a `j` loop at all.

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks. I know i have to strongly typed it. this is just testing the logic.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you. Don't know why i didn't think about it.